# How do you keep track of temporary threads of conversation online

Tags: bookmarks

Often when I post a comment or answer on a site I like to keep an eye out for additional responses from other people, possibly replying again if appropriate. Sometimes I'll bookmark a page for a while, other times I'll end up re-googling keywords to locate the post again. I've always thought there should be something better than my memory for keeping track of pages I care about for a few days to a week.

Does anyone any clever ideas for this type of thing? Is there a micro-delicious type of online app with a bookmarklet for very short term followup?

---

**Update** I think I should clarify. I wasn't asking about Stack Overflow specifically - on the "read/write web" in general I add comments to blog posts, respond to google group threads, etc. It's that sort of mish-mash of individual pages on random sites that I would care to keep track of for seven-to-ten days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stackoverflow, I put together a little bookmarklet thing at http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com. I use it to keep track of posts that I might want to come back to later, for reference or to answer if nobody else did, or whatever. The backend automatically retrieves updates from the SO server and updates your list of bookmarklets.

Answer (score 1):

In my head mostly. I occasionally forget things, but it works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very interesting question you asked here.
I do th efollowing:

1. temp bookmarks in browser
2. just a tab in Firefox left opened for weeks :)
3. subscription to email\rss when possible. When email notification comes I often put it into special folder in my email tree.

Different logins, notification types etc are complicating following info in the web :(

Other interesting questions:

1. how to organize information storage (notes, saved web pages, forum threads etc) for current usage and as a read-only library, sync it between different PCs and USB disks, how to label (tag) it and search it
2. how to store old mails, conversations, chats,..?
3. store digital photos for future: make hard-copy printouts or just regulary rewrite it from CD to a new one

Answer (score 0):

Click on your username, then Responses.