# What is the best way you've found to keep track of all of the programming information out there?

Tags: bookmarks

Although this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161114/how-do-you-keep-track-of-temporary-threads-of-conversation-online)
and this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230789/keeping-track-of-opensource-freeweare-plugins-etc) are close to what I'm asking, I believe there may be a more developer centric solution out there.

So, SO - what do you use to keep track of all of the great information that you come across on a daily basis but can't afford to read at the time.   I currently use del.icio.us but figured I'd poll the SO community to see if I was missing something.

Comment: This should be a community wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would definitely recommend [Evernote](http://evernote.com/).  I use it to keep snippets of code, project documentation, ideas, passwords, and with the web page clipper, I use it as a bookmark manager as well.  Best of all, it's free and it syncs online, so everytime I have to format my boxes or something, I just sync it back up and I'm good to go.  Can't recommend this product enough.

Answer (score 4):

I use del.icio.us, too. I have the toolbar for firefox, and it's great!
[EDIT:] OneNote is also good.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Notebook](https://www.google.com/googlenotebook/faq.html) is great for code snippets, programming links and relevant articles.

[image]

It autosaves, is indexed and has search functionality.

Comment: Actually google has ceased development on Notebook and has closed it too new users.  Article: http://www.pcworld.com/article/157734/google_kills_services_notebook_dodgeball_others_gone.html

Comment: Here's the official announcement: http://googlenotebookblog.blogspot.com/2009/01/stopping-development-on-google-notebook.html

Answer (score 2):

If it's a difficult concept, or something I might refer to more than once, I generally print it. Then when I'm done with it I file it. Where filing generally means "put on the pile of other papers to your right". If that pile exceeds a certain threshold, say 10 centimeters, I move it to another pile. \o/

Answer (score 2):

Since Google Notebook was 'closed', i switched to [ubernote](http://www.ubernote.com)

Answer (score 1):

I love Microsoft OneNote - simple UI, no Save button, build-in instant search (including OCR!), integration with Outlook.

Also I use Google's Notebook, unfortunately Google [is not going](http://googlenotebookblog.blogspot.com/2009/01/stopping-development-on-google-notebook.html) is not going to develop it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I keep all of my book marks organized. I just add more categories when I need them.

[Bookmarks http://glidertools.net/org.png](http://glidertools.net/org.png)

Comment: I did this on my office comp, and then found that when I switched cos, I lost all my bookmarks... Nowadays I use delicious.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Evernote and quite liked it - you can store all kinds on information there using either their web interface or a small locally installed app (which I find more convenient). Searching through your data works really well, and Evernote will even find text that's actually contained in an image (ideal for photos of flip charts etc.).
Currently I'm also experimenting with Ubernote...

Answer (score 0):

Everytime i find some blog post that seems more signal than noise, i print it. Every day i spend 2 hours in public transportation reading, if i dont have anything printed, i read some programming book.

While reading all that from a big list of blogs( [codinghorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/), [joelonsoftware](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/),[debuggable](http://debuggable.com/), etc) is very helpful, and the **books** do a part of the trick, the truth is you have to be picky in which subjects you want to really keep up to date and follow a lot of sites if you want to be "the first" to know of the big stuff. But the diference between the first and "everyone else" is like 3 days if the news are important so really is not worth if for most of us.

Comment: i hope you recycle after reading, else you're going to build up a big stack of papers :P

Comment: Actually i have a GBC binding machine and compile documents about some topics... friends and other programers usually come to my house to code and pick some of them... its not THAT bad if you think im actually using the paper(instade of the gov and other places just using them for paperwork)

Answer (score 0):

I browse with Firefox, so I use [Foxmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2410) to organize and sync. all my bookmarks across all my computers (you can also access them on a web page)

I have a special folder called "Brain" where I store all my good code links, generally i just store obscure little hacks that are hard to find, along with some of the good programming blogs / sites I visit often. I organize them using sub folders etc.

Also, when I come across an article and I don't have time to read it, I just [Read It Later](http://readitlaterlist.com/), then when  I have time I read it over, either I trash it, or bookmark it.

Also, I subscribe to a bunch of different sites using Google Reader.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of setting up a wiki for myself but I've never gotten to it. That's how I usually like to organize my information, that way I can access it from wherever I need it.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://codenpaste.com,

My notes are organized around a single concept or idea and i use the search to retrieve them. I may add tags from time to time for exploration with the tag tree.

It helped me learn Python and keep track of examples and alternative methods.

Disclaimer: This is a link to my website and app

Comment: Based on the URL of your link containing your user name/profile site, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must* disclose that it's your site in your post. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).